# In a generator, equality to yield

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Let's say that exists a function as such:

```
def subroutine():
    While True:    
        value = yield
        yield value**2
```

For a fact, I know that the output is a generator that squares the input, and this subroutine is run after other generator(s) have been priorly run. However, I don't understand how `value = yield` actually gets its value.

Comment: It's extending from mere generation of values to a true coroutine. Read the section on coroutines on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31042491/364696). The duplicate is technically asking the question from the other way around (they found `send`, which is how you use a generator of the form you're asking about), but it answers your question completely.

Comment: Now seems clear to me.